# Como resolver o Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

olá tenho o seguinte código:

```
var player = videojs('MY_VIDEO_1');

player.on('ended', function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "",
      context: document.body,
      success: function (s, x) {
        $(this).html(s);
    })
};
```

e esse erro aparece no console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token como resolvo?

Comment: você sabe o que o `ajax` faz e o que deveria passar na url?

Comment: Está Sem Url Pois é a página que o usuario está que é para ser recarregada , e eu já resolvi problema era só adicionar mais um "};".